# Load dropdown list based on another dropdown selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Load dropdown list based on another dropdown selected item
Here my js :

```
$("#Ownerstate").change(function () {

    var procemessage = "<option value=`0`> Please wait...</option>";
    $("#OwnerAgency").html(procemessage).show();
    var url = "/Index/GetAgencyState/";

    // Get state code
    var Ownerstate = $("#Ownerstate :selected").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { statecode: Ownerstate },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (carData) {
            if (carData.length > 1) {

                $("#OwnerAgency").prop("disabled", false);
            }
            var select = $("#OwnerAgency");
            select.html('');
            $.each(carData, function (index, itemData) {
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: itemData.Value,
                    text: itemData.Text
                }));
            });
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
});
```

Not getting load dropdownlist

Comment: Are you getting data in ajax call?

Comment: where's the issue, DropDown's change event is getting fired or not, ajax call is succeeded or not , what error are you facing and at which line?
Please describe your problem in detail

Comment: yes, method get fried, but data not shown in dropdownlist

Comment: Please, show your response from the server. Problem could be because you did not specify "dataType" property for ajax object. I guess it`s json in your case.